# Convert EST, CST and DST timezones to unix timestamp in Pytz Module in Python 3

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, pytz

I have a date that comes in the following format:

`2019-12-13 20:18 EST` or `2019-12-13 20:18 DST`or `2019-12-13 20:18 CST`

**I would like to convert them to `unix timestamp`**.

I am using `Pytz` module.

So far, I have tried using `datetime` module in the following way:

```
time_est = '2019-12-13 20:18 EST'

datetime.datetime.strptime(time_est, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z')
```

This does not seem to work either. Any suggestions out there or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: side-note: `%z` is for parsing UTC offsets, like e.g. `'+00:00'` will be parsed to UTC. there's also `%Z` which will parse very specific abbreviations, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). however, this is a) platform-dependent, and b) it won't actually set the tzinfo attribute of the resulting datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zone name abbreviations are ambiguous in many cases (one abbreviation for different time zones, [see e.g. here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)), so it is best to explicitly define what your abbreviations mean. You can do so by supplying a mapping dict to dateutil's parser.

```
import dateutil

tzmapping = {'EST': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/New_York'),
             'EDT': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/New_York'),
             'CST': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago'),
             'CDT': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
             # add more if needed...}

time_eastern = '2019-12-13 20:18 EST'

dtobj = dateutil.parser.parse(time_eastern, tzinfos=tzmapping)
# datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 13, 20, 18, tzinfo=tzfile('US/Eastern'))

time_unix = dtobj.timestamp()
# 1576286280.0
```

If you *must* use pytz, you'll have to ignore `EST` in the string, parse to naive datetime, localize to the appropriate time zone and then take the timestamp:

```
import datetime
import pytz

eastern = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
dtobj = eastern.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(time_eastern, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M EST'))
time_unix = dtobj.timestamp()
# 1576286280.0
```