# Timezone conversion in python using strptime and strftime

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I got my email in mbox format and I am trying to convert that into csv format using the python code. I am encountering some problems in timezone

```
 if 'Date' in message:
            header.append('Date')
            date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(message['Date'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
            date_time_obj = date_time_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.cet)            
            print(date_time_obj)
            row.append(str(date_time_obj.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')))
        else:
            header.append('Date')
            row.append('')
```

I am getting a value error for time zone. Since its in bracket I don't know how to deal with it

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d792bf07c081> in <module>
    135         if 'Date' in message:
    136             header.append('Date')
--> 137             date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(message['Date'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    138             datetime_object = datetime_object.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    139             print(date_time_obj)

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    566     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    567     format string."""
--> 568     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    569     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    570     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    350                          (data_string, format))
    351     if len(data_string) != found.end():
--> 352         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
    353                           data_string[found.end():])
    354 

ValueError: unconverted data remains:  (CET)
```

Kindly help

Comment: Could you include `message['date']` in your question.

Comment: strptime won't parse time zone abbreviations like `CET` (as the error tells you). You could use dateutil 's parser with a `tzinfos` mapping dict, e.g. mapping CET to an appropriate IANA name like 'Europe/Berlin'.

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Wed, 13 Jan 2021 14:46:41 +0100 (CET)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z%Z'
I don't know what to do with (CET)

Comment: An illustration of my comment; see my answer here: [Convert EST, CST and DST timezones to unix timestamp in Pytz Module in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263556/convert-est-cst-and-dst-timezones-to-unix-timestamp-in-pytz-module-in-python-3)